How to insert nodes based on matches and node quantities
I have a xml structure like this:
<nc>
    <mod>
        <grp id="d0e9f2f84">
            <des>GROUP_33</des>
            <num>--33</num>
            <seq>33</seq>
            <des2>GROUP_33</des2>
            <art>
                <num>15-33-101-00678</num>
            </art>
        </grp>
        <art>
            <num>15-36-072-00000</num>
        </art>
        <art>
            <num>13-42-099-30002</num>
        </art>
        <art>
            <num>15-42-001-45331</num>
        </art>
    </mod>
    <mod>
        <grp id="d0e9f2f84">
            <des>GROUP_33</des>
            <num>--33</num>
            <seq>33</seq>
            <des2>GROUP_33</des2>
            <art>
                <num>35-33-101-40678</num>
            </art>
        </grp>
        <art>
            <num>11-42-045-41002</num>
        </art>
        <art>
            <num>12-42-101-46331</num>
        </art>
    </mod>
</nc>

Normally the correct structure is /nc/mod/grp/art but sometimes i have articles (art) that are orphans such as /nc/mod/art.
I am trying to automatise the following. When i have orphan articles, insert a node group (grp) and depending on the second sequence of the articles number (num) for example ([0-9]{2}-42) insert a grp node.
My try with this code snipet:
let $input:=doc("file:/C:/Users/FOB/Documents/git_documentation/private/test_mod_art.xml")
    return
        for $ii in $input//mod/art[not(ancestor::grp)] return 
        if ($ii[matches(num, '^[0-5][0-9]-36')]) then
        
        insert node <grp id="d0e1f2f21"><des>GROUP_36</des><num>--36</num><seq>36</seq><des2>GROUP_36</des2></grp> before $ii
        
        else if ($ii[matches(num, '^[0-5][0-9]-42')]) then
        
        insert node <grp id="d0e1f2f23"><des>GROUP_42</des><num>--42</num><seq>42</seq><des2>GROUP_42</des2></grp> before $ii        
        else
        ()

It works, but this code doesn't take into account the fact, that sometimes we have more than one node who matches '^[0-5][0-9]-42', for example.
So i need to detect those and group it before insertion of a group node. I have read some articles with the function distinct-values (at the moment my saxon processor doesn't accept the group by clause), tried some code, but unfortunately I don't have enough knowledge to be able to understand it.
How can i achieve this, could some friendly souls give a try specially so that I can understand?
Thank you!
Expected result:
<nc>
    <mod>
        <grp id="d0e9f2f84">
            <des>GROUP_33</des>
            <num>--33</num>
            <seq>33</seq>
            <des2>GROUP_33</des2>
            <art>
                <num>15-33-101-00678</num>
            </art>
        </grp>
        <grp id="d0e5f2f12">
            <des>GROUP_36</des>
            <num>--36</num>
            <seq>36</seq>
            <des2>GROUP_36</des2>
        </grp>
        <art>
            <num>15-36-072-00000</num>
        </art>
        <grp id="d0e5f2f32">
            <des>GROUP_42</des>
            <num>--42</num>
            <seq>42</seq>
            <des2>GROUP_42</des2>
    </grp>
        <art>
            <num>13-42-099-30002</num>
        </art>
        <art>
            <num>15-42-001-45331</num>
        </art>
    </mod>
    <mod>
        <grp id="d0e9f2f84">
            <des>GROUP_33</des>
            <num>--33</num>
            <seq>33</seq>
            <des2>GROUP_33</des2>
            <art>
                <num>35-33-101-40678</num>
            </art>
        </grp>
        <grp id="d0e5f2f33">
            <des>GROUP_42</des>
            <num>--42</num>
            <seq>42</seq>
            <des2>GROUP_42</des2>
    </grp>
        <art>
            <num>11-42-045-41002</num>
        </art>
        <art>
            <num>12-42-101-46331</num>
        </art>
    </mod>
</nc>


Which version and edition of Saxon do you use exactly? If the group by fails you might want to post a minimal but complete sample that fails to allow us to fix it. And the input sample seems to have (at least) two mod child elements of the nc root element while the expected result seems to have only a single mod child element, I don't see how your XQuery code that "works" would reduce the number of mod elements. So you need to clarify what other rules need to be applied for update.

Thank you Martin. You are right, i push the trigger too fast. In my model, yes i can have maybe many , and the expected result, doesn't reflect it. I will update it. As saxon processor i have the version SAXON EE 9.5.1.5. And i am quite surprised that your code works. I have read somewhere that i would need a 9.6 version to use the group by clause. If you still have some time to spare to show me the same expected result but with the distinct-values function for xquery 1.0?. Thank you for your time.

No, sorry, in 2024 where Saxon 11 and 12 are the supported versions and XQuery 3.1 exists for a decade I am not trying to rework an XQuery 3.1 example to XQuery 1.0.

As for grouping to then only insert a new element for the first element in each group see whether the following helps:
declare ordering ordered;

declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:indent 'yes';


let 
  $input := doc('file:/C:/Users/FOB/Documents/git_documentation/private/test_mod_art.xml'),
  $group_id_map := map { '36' : 'd0e1f2f21', '42' : 'd0e1f2f23' }
return
  for $art at $pos in $input//mod/art[not(ancestor::grp)][matches(num, '^[0-5][0-9]-(36|42)')]
  group by $group_nr := replace($art/num, '^[0-5][0-9]-(36|42).*', '$1')
  order by $pos[1]
  for $art1 in $art[1] 
  return
    insert node <grp id="{$group_id_map($group_nr)}"><des>GROUP_{$group_nr}</des><num>--{$group_nr}</num><seq>{$group_nr}</seq><des2>GROUP_{$group_nr}</des2></grp> before $art1

